# Having a C++ program terminate when there is no input

Tags: c++, io, termination

I'd like to start by saying I am very new to this, so please forgive me if there is a relatively trivial solution to this. I learned here, that we can do a while(std::cin>>inputs){} loop to repeatedly do what we want to, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this program to terminate if you input a completely empty input (hitting enter without putting in any information). I will include my code below, other than this, it works just how i want it to. It's a simple Caesar Cipher. It properly terminates when an invalid input is given, for example, d 15 (this is backwards from what is requested), but entering no input at all, by just hitting enter, doesn't terminate the program. Thank you in advance <3.

```
    #include <iostream>

std::string caesarencrypt(std::string ptext, int shift){
    std::string ctext= "";

    for(int i=0;i<ptext.length();i++){
        if(islower(ptext[i])){
            ptext[i]=toupper(ptext[i]);
        }; /* turns everything into uppercase letters, which ASCII vary from 65 to 65+26=91 */
        ctext += char( int( ptext[i]+shift-65 )%26  +65); /* take each letter, add the shift, subtract the value that makes it ASCII (65), take mod 26, then add the ASCII value again */

    }

    return ctext;

}
/* to decrypt, set shift=-shift */

int main(){
    int shiftval;
    std::string ptxt;
    std::cout<< "Please input the shift value, then the plaintext, seperated by a space"<<std::endl;
    while(std::cin>>shiftval>>ptxt){
        std::cout << "Plaintext:" << ptxt <<"\n";
        std::cout <<"Ciphertext:" << caesarencrypt(ptxt,shiftval)<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For an even simpler program demonstrating the problem, you may observe the same behavior in the following Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion program.

```
// F to C temperature conversion, 1/31/19 TJMELKA
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double far;
    int cel;

    std::cout << "deg(F) to deg(C) conversion" << std::endl;

    while(std::cin >> far){
        cel=0.555556*(far-32);
        std::cout << "The temperature in Celsius is, with the decimals truncated: " << cel << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;



}
```

Comment: The two major operating systems (Windows and POSIX) both have special key-sequences that sends an "end of file" to the application. On Windows it's `Ctrl-Z` and on POSIX (e.g. Linux and macOS) it's `Ctrl-D`. This is noted by the input operation and will cause the input loops you show to end.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, there is no way to "hard code" this into how the program works, then?

Comment: The duplicate question @NathanOliver tagged this as i believe answers my question. Thank you, everyone.

Comment: The big problem is how do your program decide that there's no input to be read? Sure you could have some kind of polling and timeouts (using OS-specific functionality) to stop waiting for input after a certain time, but what if the user really wants to continue using your program but had to do something else for a minute of two? Unless you document it and tell the user *very* explicitly, most users would expect your program to read input forever until *they* decide that it's enough and use either some special input of the EOF sequence to terminate the input.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Alot of stuff to figure out, going from Mathematica/Matlab to C++. Lots to learn (: Thank you again, everyone.